# DumpSave'ing while lengthy program runs

Tags: files-and-directories, save, import, dumpsave

tldr: is there a way to load all files following a structure/append to DumpSave file

i would like to run a script following the structure:

```
Get['lib.wl']
data = initializeDataSet[] 
DumpSave['save0', data]

result1 = compute1[]
DumpSave['save1', result1]
Clear[result1]

.
.
.

resultn = computen[]
DumpSave['saven', resultn]
Clear[resultn]
```

is there a good way to load all saves without going >>save0 to >>saven. Or is this manual work needed? A `Get[name]` where name allows for joker would suffice, but I don't think it exists. Putting them into a separate folder seems sensible.

Just saving at the end doesn't seem viable/safe to me in case of an unexpected early exit.

Edit: just discovered `FileNames[]` is a thing.
the solution would be like:

```
names = FileNames[pattern,{directory}]
Do[Get[fileName], {fileName, names}]
```

Comment: please add you solution as an answer rather than part of the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Get/@ FileNames["save*"]`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Get /@ StringTemplate["save``"] /@ Range[1, 5]
```