# Is there any means of Importing folder with images( .jpeg) directly?

Tags: import

I am using Mathematica for training dataset of fruits, for which i need to import the collection of images.
Can we import a folder with images directly or Do we need to import each image in iteration format?

Comment: You may want to read the documentation page for [out of core image processing for neural networks](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksLargeDatasets.html#798689896)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Import[FileNameJoin[{"Path", "To", "Directory", "*.jpeg"}], "JPEG"]` is undocumented but will work (for now, subject to change).

I recommend perhaps `FileSystemMap` for this task. Simply `Import[#, "JPEG"] & /@ FileNames["/Path/To/Directory/*.jpeg"]` will work just fine as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your Assistance..!!
I tried the same with map function. 
Map[Import, FileNames["*_100.jpg", location]]

Answer (score 1):

afaik. there is no easier way than doing

```
images = {}
names = FileNames[pattern,{directory}]
Do[AppendTo[images = Import[fileName]], {fileName, names}]
```

with

```
pattern = "*.png"
directory = "YourDirectoryName"
```

The code is untested but should work. Sadly i cannot easily test the code lacking such directory.

code from my old question (modified): [DumpSave'ing while lengthy program runs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180849/dumpsaveing-while-lengthy-program-runs)

Comment: This is a bit over complicated, please see my response.

Comment: @GenericAccountName Good call to simplify that Do loop, i didn't have time to think about that. I made so many variables for the code to be readable. Thanks for pointing out the FileSystemMap, it seems very usefull.